# Is there any way to switch off the display and switch it back on explicitly?

Tags: windows-7, display, automation

I turn off my display using nircommand which uses Window's default switch off monitor function. The problem with this is that, the display turns on when I move my mouse or type something in the keyboard(like controlling spotify).

I need to shut down the monitor and not have it turn itself on on an event, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use the button on the monitor?

Comment: @EBGreen The way my computer monitor is positioned makes it hard for me to reach it

Comment: I checked with AutoHotKey, it's the same, there doesn't seem to be a command which allows to turn off the screen. Only to put to stand-by.

Comment: My comment was at least partially tongue in cheek. I suspect that you will not be able to do this. The best thing that I could think of would be to run a script that will use nircommand to sleep the monitor every 5 seconds or so then have a hot key to kill the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if anything else fails on the software side, there's always the ["hardware" solution](http://amzn.com/B0087EIDRS):

[image: Remote control Socket]

One button, switch on and off the display, and it's not out of reach.

Comment: *(Dear USA, your power sockets look sad. Or shocked. Either way, it's disturbing)*

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Windows 7, you could try switching the display with Win+P to a position in which it would redirect all to the external display.

More directly, you could make a shortcut to the program which is called by this shortcut:

```
Switch to External (and black out the main screen)
%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /external

Switch back to the main screen 
%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
```

Of course, this would work only if you don't actually have an external display plugged.

Comment: Nice Idea, but it doesn't work in my computer :/

Comment: Hm, I guess it works only if you have a way to plug an external output to begin with?

Comment: Plausibly, I do not have another port in my mobo :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this [with C#](http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/03/turn-off-your-monitor-via-code-c.html). Personally if I were doing this, I would write a small executable in C# that simply takes an argument for which action it will perform and then write a wrapper in autoit that monitors for whatever criteria it needs to take any action using that executable.

Comment: Umm, If I do not get better answer, I will write my own.

Comment: That's the same command I was finding to use with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=27738) (AutoHotKey can use "SendMessage"). It's a standby signal only, unfortunately, and it will wake up on mouse movement or key press.